# Is a surjective map a quotient map when its kernel is given by the action of a finite group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a surjective and continuous map. Let $G$ be a group acting continuously on $X$: for every $g \in G$ the map induced from the group action $\phi_{g}\colon X\to X$ is supposed to be continuous. Assume that $f(x) = f(x^{\prime})$ if and only if there exists a $g \in G$ so that $\phi_{g}(x) = x^{\prime}$. This means that $\overline{f} \colon X/\tilde{}_{\small{G}} \to Y$ is a continuous bijective map.

My question: If $G$ is a finite group (e.g. $S_{n}$) is it then true that $f$ is a quotient map? Or in general: are there conditions on the group which guarantee that $f$ is a quotient map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way to see that $f$ is not necessarily a quotient map, is to take any
continuous bijection that is not a homeomorphism. In that case $G$ must be
the trivial group and $X/G  \cong X$, but a bijective quotient map must be a homeomorpism.

More generally, $f$ is a quotient map iff $\overline f$ is a homeomorphism, so
suppose that there is combination of $X, Y, f, G$ such that $f$ is a quotient
map, then with a slightly coarser topology on $Y$ you have another counterexample.
I think that rules out any reasonable conditions on $G$.